# How to runserver and see website for github project files

Tags: django, github, view, web

New to Django, I am trying to view the website with its associated functionality generated by the project files here:

https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz

When I use the usual: manage.py runserver on the command prompt, it says that there is no manage.py file, and there isn't.

Worryingly, I followed the instructions for installation which suggested: Run pip install -r requirements.txt

...and my computer proceeded to de-install Django 2.0? What is that about, and can anyone explain how to restore settings if I messed them up completely.

The second part of the instructions for installation asks to change something in the INSTALLED_APPS and urls.py section, but where? There is nothing in the root directory and it doesn't specify which folder/app to do this in?

I don't quite understand how to "run" (see/view) these files and see this quiz app in process on my local host. What do I need to add? Why is the manage.py file not included?

Any explanation or something to point me in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The github project contains only Django apps. Not whole project. You need to integrate this in your Django project. You can run it by following below steps.

1. Create New Django Project
2. Clone [github](https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz/) repo in your project. Run following commands in your project directory.

> git clone https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz.git
>
> mv django_quiz/* .
>
> rm -rf django_quiz

3. Add `essay`, `true_false`, `quiz`, `multichoice` in your installed apps
4. Install requirements with `pip install -r requirements.txt`
5. Create Migrations
6. Run Migrations
7. Add `url(r'^q/', include('quiz.urls'))` in your project urls.
8. Run server with `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Can you explain point 2. How is that done? Assuming I have a project, with a manage.py, do I then copy all the other files into that project? If so, what remains in the root directory?It isn't clear. Could you give me an example with the files above?

Comment: I have added description for #2.

Comment: Thank you. No 4, will uninstall the current version of Django and install the 1.6 version, or am I wrong? Is there a way to do this without uninstalling my current version of Django?

Comment: Project in github is created for older version of Django. You can remove that from reqirements.txt file but you will face compatibility issues due to different version of your project and version in which github project is build. You can run project by solving those issues.